# Import boto from local library

Tags: python, boto

I'm trying to use boto as a downloaded library, rather than installing it globally on my machine. I'm able to import boto, but when I run boto.connect_dynamodb() I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named dynamodb.layer2
```

Here's my file structure:

```
project/
    project/
        __init__.py
        libraries/
            __init__.py
            flask/
            boto/
        views/
            ....
        modules/
            __init__.py
            db.py
            ....
        templates/
            ....
        static/
            ....
    runserver.py
```

And the contents of the relevant files as follows:

## project/project/modules/db.py

```
from project.libraries import boto

conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(
  aws_access_key_id='<YOUR_AWS_KEY_ID>',
  aws_secret_access_key='<YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY>')
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have dynamodb library? Probably boto is trying to do just import dynamodb.layer2. And you have it in some other place like project.librarys.boto. Maybe adding path to dynamodb to sys.path is the solution?

Comment: Start with checking what you have in sys.path. Just import sys and print sys.path. This is list with pathes where python look for libraries. You can add your path, for example sys.path.append('[...]/project/libraries/boto/dynamodb') .

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using virtualenv.  This is exactly the situation that it is designed for.

If that's not possible for some reason, make sure you add the boto installation directory to your PYTHONPATH.  So, from your example something like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path_to_project/project/libraries
```

should allow things to work.  But again, virtualenv is your friend.

Comment: To add to this - I'm new to all of this, but I have virtualenv installed, but had to run 'source bin/activate' in the terminal first.. before diving into the python interactive terminal

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with garnaat on the virtues (no pun intended) of virtualenv, I think your problem may be that your version of boto doesn't have DynamoDB support. For example, I installed boto using pip recently, and I am at version 2.0. You can check your version with `boto.Version`

DynamoDB support was added in version 2.2.0, according to the release notes (see link below).

Easiest thing for you to do (if you have git installed) is to clone it from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/boto/boto.git
```

Or if you don't have git installed and don't want to install it, you can get the latest release tag (2.3.0) from GitHub ([ZIP](https://github.com/boto/boto/zipball/2.3.0) or [tarball](https://github.com/boto/boto/tarball/2.3.0)).

#### References

- https://github.com/boto/boto
- https://github.com/boto/boto/wiki/Release-Notes-for-boto-2.2.0